# i want to modify to be able to get api using axios

Tags: javascript, c#, reactjs, .net, axios

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:7096/api/User/Login' from origin 'http://localhost:3001' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

Axios

I look forward to fixing this. Because I use axios to get the api but it doesn't work